# Backbone - Reusing Views vs Creating new Views

Tags: backbone.js, view

Writing my first Backbone app - came across a predicament wherein i am unable to choose which is the best way to move forward.

Scenario : User clicks an edit button , a new view is loaded . Approach is as below.

```
    renderEditView: function(){     

       if(my.namespace.view){
             my.namespace.view.render();
       }else{
             my.namespace.view= new editView({model:my.namespace.model});
       }
    }
```

Basically, i am assigning my view to a namespaced variable and resuing it as required. Didn't face any problems as such. 
But some advocate recreating the View again using `new editView({model:xxx});` whenever the edit button is clicked . i Would like to know which one is the better practice and why?

P.S: i am aware of the 'event ghosting' problem in BB apps, and the excellent solution provided by [Derick Bailey](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) .But still would love to know the pros and cons between the approaches.

Comment: My 2¢: I've been a Backbone user for a few years now, and have recently moved most of my UI layer to React. My opinion is to re-create every time. Mostly around legacy events, but just for a cleaner feel, ie. removing (potentially) stale HTML...

Comment: @benhowdle89 Roger...Just wanted more opinions !. I am currently recreating new views every-time for one part of the app, whereas using name-spaced views for other parts !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an opinion, because either way will work if you (as you mention) take care of cleaning up previous views if you decide to instantiate a new one every time you want to re-render. It's important to avoid duplicating lingering events from every instance that you want to replace by creating a new one.
Personally I have used both strategies and never had problems with them so far.
When re-using a view, I bind the view as a property to the controller object that renders the view, pretty much the same way you do it.
Theoretically, I don't see a reason to re-instantiate a view if it was already created before. It isn't that you really require a new instance, it's just that you want to re-render it.

**Sidenote**
For re-rendering views, Backbone Marionette offers `regions`, which are convenience objects that allow you to do things like:

```
var myView = new MyView(); 
var region = new Marionette.Region({el: "#container"}); 
region.show(myView);
```

In case you would decide to instantiate a new view every time, these regions take care that previously rendered views are properly cleaned up.

Comment: Ah, if only Marionette was an option ! Would like to try that in the next project. Planning to remove all the recurring new View instance creation and move to re-using the views.

Comment: Good idea! The article from Derick Bailey that you added provides all the info you need to properly remove your view instances from memory.